# How build constructor for static class

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Is there a way to wrap up a bunch of static fields into its own class?

I tried doing something like this, but I can stop at the constructor.

What should I pass into the constructor?

```
public static class CarPartsLibary
{
    private static string factoryId = "fgk4548j4t5jig3";
    private static string engineId = "fgfgj34lk45l3lj";
    private static string bodyId = "45kjgiu590dkjr";
    private static bool typeCar = true;
    private static bool autoStart = true;
    private static bool allWheelDrive = true;
    private static bool dieselEngine = false;

    static CarPartsLibary()
    {            
    }
}
```

I want to put all the static fields into its own class so that I can do stuff like this:

```
var pl = CarPartsLibary();

var car = pl.typeCar;
var factory = GetLocation(pl.factoryId);
```

Thanks!

Comment: You mean add public static properties? Not sure what you are looking for. You don't even need the constructor there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When having a static class one does not have instances of it and accesing it is through the: `ClassName.FieldName`. (Also to access the fields they way you wanted they should be `public`)

```
public static class CarPartsLibary
{
    public static string factoryId = "fgk4548j4t5jig3";
    public static string engineId = "fgfgj34lk45l3lj";
    public static string bodyId = "45kjgiu590dkjr";
    public static bool typeCar = true;
    public static bool autoStart = true;
    public static bool allWheelDrive = true;
    public static bool dieselEngine = false;
}

var car = CarPartsLibary.typeCar;
var factory = GetLocation(CarPartsLibary.factoryId);
```

Read more on MSDN about [static classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx) and using them